# Probabilities when rolling more dice than needed

Tags: statistics, earthdawn

I would like to know whether adding an extra die whose result does not count towards a total into a normal dice roll would affect the probabilities.

i.e. in Earthdawn, if a player rolls 2D8+1D6 and adds a D20 into the mix but ignores the result of the D20, does that change the probability of the other dice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No.

Die rolls are independent of each other. The ignored die will have no bearing on the rest, other than possible physical collisions that will not influence the results in any predictable way that would make any result more or less probable. (It's difficult to prove a negative, but this answer follows from the principles of discrete probability.)

Note that rolling a die and ignoring it is essentially the same as not rolling it at all, or rolling it in another room, or rolling it inside a closed box, none of which would affect the information we have for predicting the likelihood of any given results for the other dice (which is all that probability represents anyway).